# Error in running a project in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio v2.2.0.12. I created a new app, but when I build it, it gets stuck on the `gradle Build Running` step.

[image]

The output in the terminal is :

```
[  22589]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
[  22675]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'plaid' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
[  29788]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'Discover-Delhi' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
[  35374]   WARN - s.idea.run.util.MultiUserUtils - Error parsing output of `am get-current-user`: usage: am [subcommand] [options]
usage:... 
Loading library manifest /home/cortana/AndroidProjects/FirstApp/app/src/main/nevercreated.xml
Merging main manifest /home/cortana/AndroidProjects/FirstApp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Merging library manifest /home/cortana/AndroidProjects/FirstApp/app/src/main/nevercreated.xml
Merging manifest with lower nevercreated.xml:1:1-12:12
Merging application with lower nevercreated.xml:3:5-11:19
[1339049]   WARN - .workspace.NdkWorkspaceManager - NDK support for project 'FirstApp' is disabled because it's not a valid Android project 
[1339338]   WARN - ools.idea.run.util.LaunchUtils - calling isWatchFaceApp when facet is not ready yet
```

I think this error ->

> [  35374]   WARN - s.idea.run.util.MultiUserUtils - Error parsing output of `am get-current-user`: usage: am [subcommand] [options]

is why the build is not getting completed. It never took more than a few seconds on previous versions of android studio and its been a half hour waiting now. Can this be why its not building? And if yes, how can I correct this?

Comment: did you clean and rebuild your project before running your project?

Comment: Yes I did. It still gets stuck on the `gradle Build Running`.

Comment: Did you get any solution after that? I am facing the similar issue with the same warnings.

Comment: In my case it was due to intenet connection issue by which it was not able to download gradle.